# Any one could help with this NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to know the traces of electron and its velocity based on the equation

```
D[\[Gamma][t] ur[t], t] = \[Omega]E - \[Omega]B*u\[Theta][t]
D[\[Gamma][t] u\[Theta][t], t] = \[Omega]B*ur[t]
\[Gamma][t] = 1/Sqrt[1 - \[Beta][t]^2]
```

(1) Then I wrote the codes

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] ;
SetOptions[{Plot, LogLogPlot, ParametricPlot}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontWeight -> Bold}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Medium];
e = 4.8*10^-10; me = 9.1*10^-28; c = 3*10^10;
E0 = 3.4*10^10*(10^-4*1/3); B0 = 11.4*10^4;
\[Omega]E = (e*E0)/me;(*\[Omega]E\[TildeEqual]6*10^23*)
\[Omega]B = (e*B0)/(me*c);(*\[Omega]B\[TildeEqual]2*10^12*)

\[Beta][t_] := (r'[t]^2 + (r[t]*\[Theta]'[t])^2)^(1/2)/c
\[Gamma][t_] := (1 - \[Beta][t]^2)^(-1/2)
D\[Gamma][t_] := D[\[Gamma][t], t]

t0 = 10^-12; r0 = 1*10^-4; tMax = 10 t0;
equ = {D[\[Gamma][t]*r'[t], t] == \[Omega]E - \[Omega]B*r[t]*\[Theta]'[t], 
       D[\[Gamma][t]*r[t]*\[Theta]'[t], t] == \[Omega]B*r'[t]};
ic = {r[0] == r0, \[Theta][0] == r0,  r'[0] == r0/c, \[Theta]'[0] == r0/c};

{rsol, \[Theta]sol} = NDSolveValue[{equ, ic}, {r, \[Theta]}, {t, 0, tMax}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
x[t_] := rsol[t] Cos[\[Theta]sol[t]]
y[t_] := rsol[t] Sin[\[Theta]sol[t]]
u[t_] := (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2)^(1/2)

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tMax}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
LogLogPlot[u[t], {t, 10^-6 tMax, tMax}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "u"}]
```

with messages

```
NDSolveValue::nderr: Error test failure at t == 0.`; unable to continue.
```

It can not be solved and with large (wrong) initial conditions.

(2) Then I normalized the equation with 't0/c', the equation becomes

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] ;
SetOptions[{Plot, LogLogPlot, ParametricPlot}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontWeight -> Bold}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Medium];
e = 4.8*10^-10; me = 9.1*10^-28; c = 3*10^10;
E0 = 3.4*10^10*(10^-4*1/3); B0 = 11.4*10^4;
\[Omega]E = (e*E0)/me;(*\[Omega]E\[TildeEqual]6*10^23*)
\[Omega]B = (e*B0)/(me*c);(*\[Omega]B\[TildeEqual]2*10^12*)

\[Beta][t_] := (r'[t]^2 + (r[t]*\[Theta]'[t])^2)^(1/2)/c
\[Gamma][t_] := (1 - \[Beta][t]^2)^(-1/2)
D\[Gamma][t_] := D[\[Gamma][t], t]

t0 = 10^-12; r0 = 1*10^-4; tMax = 1.5*10^13;
equ = {D[\[Gamma][t]*r'[t], t] == (\[Omega]E -\[Omega]B*r[t]*\[Theta]'[t])*t0/c, 
       D[\[Gamma][t]*r[t]*\[Theta]'[t], t] == \[Omega]B*r'[t]*t0/c};
ic = {r[0] == r0, \[Theta][0] == r0, 
   r'[0] == r0/c, \[Theta]'[0] == r0/c};

{rsol, \[Theta]sol} =  NDSolveValue[{equ, ic}, {r, \[Theta]}, {t, 0, tMax}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
x[t_] := rsol[t] Cos[\[Theta]sol[t]]
y[t_] := rsol[t] Sin[\[Theta]sol[t]]
u[t_] := (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2)^(1/2)

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tMax}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
LogLogPlot[u[t], {t, 1, tMax}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "u"}]
```

with messages

```
NDSolveValue::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is 
available.
 Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

It could give some unconfirmed results but the velocity is larger than c.

(3) Equation is revised and it seems to be OK, where 'u->u/c', 't->t/t0', and initial velocity is obtained from temperature of `T0=300 eV'

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] ;
SetOptions[{Plot, LogLogPlot, ParametricPlot}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontWeight -> Bold}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Medium];
e = 4.8*10^-10; me = 9.1*10^-28; c = 3*10^10;
E0 = 3.4*10^10*(10^-4*1/3); B0 = 11.4*10^4;
\[Omega]E = (e*E0)/me;(*\[Omega]E\[TildeEqual]6*10^23*)
\[Omega]B = (e*B0)/(me*c);(*\[Omega]B\[TildeEqual]2*10^12*)
T0 = 300; (*eV*)
u0 = ((T0*1.6*10^-19)/(9.1*10^-31))^(1/2)*10^2/c;

\[Beta][t_] := (r'[t]^2 + (r[t]*\[Theta]'[t])^2)^(1/2)
\[Gamma][t_] := (1 - \[Beta][t]^2)^(-1/2)
D\[Gamma][t_] := D[\[Gamma][t], t]

t0 = 10^-12; r0 = 0.1; tMax = 100; 
equ = {D[\[Gamma][t]*r'[t], 
     t] == (\[Omega]E - \[Omega]B*r[t]*\[Theta]'[t])*t0/c, 
   D[\[Gamma][t]*r[t]*\[Theta]'[t], t] == \[Omega]B*r'[t]*t0/c};

equ = {D[\[Gamma][t]*r'[t], 
     t] == \[Omega]E*t0/c - \[Omega]B*r[t]*\[Theta]'[t]*t0, 
   D[\[Gamma][t]*r[t]*\[Theta]'[t], t] == \[Omega]B*r'[t]*t0};
ic = {r[0] == r0, \[Theta][0] == 0.1, 
   r'[0] == u0, \[Theta]'[0] == u0/r0};

{rsol, \[Theta]sol} = 
 NDSolveValue[{equ, ic}, {r, \[Theta]}, {t, 0, tMax}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
x[t_] := rsol[t] Cos[\[Theta]sol[t]]
y[t_] := rsol[t] Sin[\[Theta]sol[t]]
u[t_] := (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2)^(1/2)

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tMax}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
LogLogPlot[u[t], {t, 1, tMax}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "u"}]
```

When `tMax=100`, the velocity is less than `c`; but when tMax is very large, i.e. `tMax=1000`, the velocity is larger than `c` and with the following message

```
NDSolveValue::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

Thanks a lot!
Kun

Comment: There must be something wrong with the parameters. Do `icrule = Rule @@@ ic` and `equ /. t -> 0 /. icrule` to see second derivative at zero has to be mega large `{(r^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] == 5.97802*10^23, True}`  Not realistic.

Comment: Two error messages from: NDSolveValue Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. If you display `equ` it seems perfectly reasonable to me that it cannot solve for `r'` and `θ'` Can you find a way to give it `r'` and `θ'`?  If so then that error should go away and you might get a solution. Then the next error message is NDSolveValue Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Fix the first error and I'm guessing the second will go away.

Comment: Please include warning messages in the body of the question. Just as Mathematica prints them out to help you, so they would help us, too.  Also it makes someone searching the site with a similar problem more likely to find the Q&A in which the problem such as yours is already solved.

Comment: Did you mean to write `D[\[Gamma][t]*r[t] \[Theta]'[t], t]` instead of `D[\[Gamma][t]*r[t] \[Theta]'[t]]`?

Answer (score 1):

We can normalize equations using scales `t0` and `c` as follows

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
e = 4.8*10^-10; me = 9.1*10^-28; c = 3*10^10;
E0 = 3.4*10^10*(10^-4*1/3); B0 = 11.4*10^4;
\[Omega]E = (e*E0)/me; \[Omega]B = (e*B0)/(me*c);

\[Beta][t_] := (r'[t]^2 + (r[t]*\[Theta]'[t])^2)^(1/2)
\[Gamma][t_] := (1 - \[Beta][t]^2)^(-1/2)

equ = {D[\[Gamma][t]*r'[t], t] == 
    t0 \[Omega]E/c - t0 \[Omega]B*r[t] \[Theta]'[t], 
   D[\[Gamma][t]*r[t] \[Theta]'[t]] == t0 \[Omega]B*r'[t]};
ic = {r[0] == r0, \[Theta][0] == r0, r'[0] == 0, \[Theta]'[0] == 0};
t0 = 10^-12; r0 = 1*10^-4;
```

Then we can solve equations with option

```
{rsol, \[Theta]sol} = 
 NDSolveValue[{equ, ic}, {r, \[Theta]}, {t, 0, 10 }, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]

x[t_] := rsol[t] Cos[\[Theta]sol[t]]
y[t_] := rsol[t] Sin[\[Theta]sol[t]]
```

Visualization

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Nice suggestions, but still not sure about the results since there are messages 'NDSolveValue::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.' when `t` is as large as `10^13`. And the velocity `u` is large than `c`.

Comment: Ok! In your question `tmax=10 t0=10^-11` , and u<c.  Why do you try 10^13 and u>c (superluminal particles)?